# Enclosing an Admin class within a Model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I've often seen examples like this in other projects' code:

```
class Modela(models.Model):
    abbr = models.CharField()
    name = models.TextField()

    class Admin:
        list_display = ('abbr', 'name',)
```

Unfortunately, when I do this in my own code and then register the model with:

```
admin.site.register(Modela)
```

...the `list_display` variable is ignored and I get the output of `__str__` for each entry in the database.

Do I really need to write separate `ModelAdmin` classes for  each class, or is there a way to do it as above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax is from a very old version of Django - pre-'newforms-admin', which merged before 1.0 was released over three years ago. It doesn't work any more, and there's absolutely no reason to use it.

If you just want to change the `list_display`, though, there isn't any need to create classes: you can pass that into the register call:

```
admin.site.register(Modela, list_display=('abbr', 'name'))
```